# Dockerfile dependency installed properly but resulting image doesn't have it

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python-software-properties
```

Running it with:

```
sudo docker build -t my_step1 .
```

I see the bottom line is:

```
Successfully built b7f1e789d8e8
```

Which looks promising. However, trying it I get:

```
avidane$ docker run -it my_step1 bash
root@e6756cdd93bd:/# add-apt-repository
bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you add `RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common` to the Dockerfile?

Comment: That works, many thanks.

Comment: @jdo You might create an answer that can be accepted by author.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite specific to Ubuntu and Debian so it probably belongs on askubuntu.com where [it's been asked already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493460/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-using-the-terminal).

In all versions of Ubuntu based on Debian **jessie**, you'll find `add-apt-repository` in the package `python-software-common`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-common
```

In all versions of Ubuntu based on Debian **wheezy**, you'll find `add-apt-repository` in the package `python-software-properties`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Tip: type `cat /etc/debian_version` in a terminal to find out which Debian version your current Ubuntu distro is based on.

All the jessie/wheezy Ubuntu versions:

```
15.10  wily       jessie  / sid
15.04  vivid      jessie  / sid
14.10  utopic     jessie  / sid
14.04  trusty     jessie  / sid  <-- the OP is using trusty/jessie
13.10  saucy      wheezy  / sid
13.04  raring     wheezy  / sid
12.10  quantal    wheezy  / sid
12.04  precise    wheezy  / sid
11.10  oneiric    wheezy  / sid
```

You can look up packages and specific files within packages here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Searching for the file `add-apt-repository` in Ubuntu trusty:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=add-apt-repository&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

```
File                            Packages 
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository     software-properties-common
```